# Comparing matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A,C$ are positive definite matrices such that $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\B^{\top}&C\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite for some matrix $B$ with suitable dimension. Define $\begin{bmatrix}E&F\\F^{\top}&G\end{bmatrix}:=\begin{bmatrix}A+D&B\\B^{\top}&C\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$, where $E,F,G$ has the same dimensions as $A,B,C$, respectively, and $D$ is positive definite.

I want to show $D^{-1}\succeq E$. Could anyone help me to approach the problem? Any helps or hints are appreciated!

Comment: What does $\succeq$ stands for?

Comment: $M_{1}\succeq M_{2}$ means $M_{1}-M_{2}$ is positive semidefinite.